# How to get one data frame from below code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, quandl

Trying to get from different timeseries, from quandl, one single dataframe.

Trying with for loop get data from thre different quandl timeseries.
Getting so far this:

```
             Open   High    Low  Close
Date
2019-04-05  145.0  145.0  138.0  140.2
             Open   High    Low  Close
Date
2019-04-05  41.29  41.59  41.03  41.05
             Open   High   Low  Close
Date
2019-04-05  12.04  12.08  11.9   11.9
```

```
import quandl
import pandas as pd

tickers=['WSE/AMICA','WSE/PZU','WSE/WIELTON']
notowania=[]

for ticker in tickers:
    raw_notowania = quandl.get(ticker, authtoken="mytoken", rows=1)[['Open', 'High','Low', 'Close']]
    print(raw_notowania)
```

Expected result is to have after for loop one single dataframe like that:

```
                 Open   High    Low  Close
     |  ticker1|
date |  ticker2|
     |  ticker3|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In loop append each `DataFrame` to `list`, join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with parameter `key`, then [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) and [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
tickers=['WSE/AMICA','WSE/PZU','WSE/WIELTON']

notowania=[]

for ticker in tickers:
    raw_notowania=quandl.get(ticker,authtoken="mytoken",rows=1)[['Open','High','Low','Close']]
    notowania.append(raw_notowania)

df = pd.concat(notowania, keys=tickers).swaplevel().sort_index(level=0)
print (df)
                          Open    High     Low   Close
2019-04-05 WSE/AMICA    145.00  145.00  138.00  140.20
           WSE/PZU       41.29   41.59   41.03   41.05
           WSE/WIELTON   12.04   12.08   11.90   11.90
```